# GraphQL "Schema must contain uniquely named types" when using Serverless

Tags: mongodb, graphql, nestjs, serverless

I'm trying to deploy a NestJS GraphQL API server with Serverless and AWS Lambda. When running the app locally I am able to use the GraphQL playground without any issues, but when running Serverless offline I get the following error:

`Error: Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named "Constellation".`

The error states that ObjectTypes `Constellation` and `Affix` are not unique. These are both `ObjectTypes` that represent the type for a field:

**MODEL SCHEMAS**

```
// character.model.ts

import mongoose, { Document, Schema as MongooseSchema } from 'mongoose';

import { Field, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@ObjectType('Constellation')
class Constellation {
  @Field(() => String)
  effect: string;

  @Field(() => Number)
  oid: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  name: string;

  @Field(() => Number)
  pos: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  icon: string;
}

@ObjectType()
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Character {
  @Field(() => String)
  _id: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId;

  @Field(() => Number)
  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true })
  oid: number;

  @Field(() => [Constellation])
  @Prop({ required: true })
  constellations: Constellation[];

  @Field(() => String)
  @Prop({ required: true })
  element: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Field(() => Number)
  @Prop({ required: true })
  rarity: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Prop({ required: true })
  icon: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Prop({ required: true })
  image: string;
}

export type CharacterDocument = Character & Document;
export const CharacterSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Character);
export default mongoose.model<CharacterDocument>(Character.name, CharacterSchema);
```

```
// artifact-set.model.ts

import mongoose, { Document, Schema as MongooseSchema } from 'mongoose';

import { Field, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@ObjectType('Affix')
export class Affix {
  @Field(() => Number)
  activation_number: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  effect: string;
}

@ObjectType()
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class ArtifactSet {
  @Field(() => String)
  _id: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId;

  @Field(() => Number)
  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true })
  oid: number;

  @Field(() => [Affix])
  @Prop({ required: true })
  affixes: Affix[];

  @Field(() => String)
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;
}

export type ArtifactSetDocument = ArtifactSet & Document;
export const ArtifactSetSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(ArtifactSet);
export default mongoose.model<ArtifactSetDocument>(ArtifactSet.name, ArtifactSetSchema);
```

**IMPORTS**

Since I've seen that importing these models could be a source of the problem, I've also included an example import:

```
import { Affix, ArtifactSet } from '../artifact-set/artifact-set.model';
```

This is imported into a `service` file in `../character/character.service` for another model, and is not imported elsewhere. The `Constellation` ObjectType is not explicitly imported anywhere else, yet is the first type to raise an error.

**serverless.yml**

```
app: server
service: server-api
useDotenv: true

package:
  patterns:
    - '!dist/**'
    - '!src/seeds/**'

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-offline

# custom:
#   serverless-offline:
#     allowCache: true

provider:
  name: aws
  profile: serverless-admin
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221

functions:
  main:
    handler: src/lambda.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: POST
          cors: true
          integration: LAMBDA
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: GET
          cors: true
          integration: LAMBDA
      - http:
          path: playground
          method: ANY
          cors: true
          integration: LAMBDA
```

**ATTEMPTS**

I've tried the following based on research of users facing similar problems:

1. Double check that imports have no typos, are all same case
2. Change class name, specify name within decorator (ex. `ObjectType('Constellation')`
3. Change imports to use absolute path (`src/../..`)
4. Use types/interfaces instead of `ObjectType`
5. Remove the mongoose default export from schemas

Comment: It might be helpful if you add the actual error. Can you add the log that shows that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be sure this was your issue, but I had the same error while using nest, and serverless-offline.

What solved it for me was adding `--allowCache` to the serverless offline command. [See Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline#usage-and-command-line-options)

```
npx serverless offline --allowCache
```

Without that, my `server` variable was not being cached, but somehow the [OrphanedReferenceRegistry](https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/blob/master/lib/schema-builder/services/orphaned-reference.registry.ts) was being cached between function calls. Each time I hit my URL my server was bootstrapped again, my ObjectType was added to the existing registry, which triggered the error when the schema was created because there were 2+ of the same ObjectType.

Here are my notes for reference in case it helps anyone with a similar issue
https://github.com/pope-12/nest-graphql-serverless-error